# WildFly Swarm apps using an external ActiveMQ broker

Tags: activemq-artemis, wildfly-swarm

I'm having a very hard time to get two WildFly swarm apps (based on 2017.9.5 version) communicate with each other over a standalone ActiveMQ 5.14.3 broker. All done using YAML config as I can't have a main method in my case.

after reading hundreds of outdated examples and inaccurate pages of documentation, I settled with following settings for both producer and consumer apps:

```
swarm:

  messaging-activemq:
    servers:
      default:
        jms-topics:
          domain-events: {}

  messaging:
    remote:
      name: remote-mq
      host: localhost
      port: 61616
      jndi-name: java:/jms/remote-mq

  remote: true
```

Now it seems that at least part of the setting is correct as the apps start except for following warning:

```
2017-09-16 14:20:04,385 WARN  [org.jboss.activemq.artemis.wildfly.integration.recovery] (MSC service thread 1-2) AMQ122018: Could not start recovery discovery on XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration=[TransportConfiguration(name=, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&localAddress=::&host=localhost], discoveryConfiguration=null, username=null, password=****, JNDI_NAME=java:/jms/remote-mq], we will retry every recovery scan until the server is available
```

Also when producer tries to send messages it just times out and I get following exception (just the last part):

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:727)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:300)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAManagedConnection.setup(ActiveMQRAManagedConnection.java:785)
    ... 127 more
Caused by: ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:724)
    ... 130 more
```

I suspect that the problem is ActiveMQ has security turned on, but I found no place to give username and password to swarm config.

The ActiveMQ instance is running using Docker and following compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  activemq:
    image: webcenter/activemq
    environment:
      - ACTIVEMQ_NAME=amqp-srv1
      - ACTIVEMQ_REMOVE_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT=true
      - ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_LOGIN=admin
      - ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD=your_password
      - ACTIVEMQ_WRITE_LOGIN=producer_login
      - ACTIVEMQ_WRITE_PASSWORD=producer_password
      - ACTIVEMQ_READ_LOGIN=consumer_login
      - ACTIVEMQ_READ_PASSWORD=consumer_password
      - ACTIVEMQ_JMX_LOGIN=jmx_login
      - ACTIVEMQ_JMX_PASSWORD=jmx_password
      - ACTIVEMQ_MIN_MEMORY=1024
      - ACTIVEMQ_MAX_MEMORY=4096
      - ACTIVEMQ_ENABLED_SCHEDULER=true

    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "5672:5672"
      - "8161:8161"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "61613:61613"
      - "61614:61614"
```

any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had bad times trying to get it working too. The following YML solved my problem:

```
swarm:
  network:
    socket-binding-groups:
      standard-sockets:
        outbound-socket-bindings:
          myapp-socket-binding:
            remote-host: localhost
            remote-port: 61616
  messaging-activemq:
    servers:
      default:
        remote-connectors:
          myapp-connector:
            socket-binding: myapp-socket-binding
        pooled-connection-factories:
          myAppRemote:
            user: username
            password: password
            connectors:
              - myapp-connector
            entries:
              - 'java:/jms/remote-mq'
```

Comment: not sure if that works, I may give it a try later. however I gave up using the YAML config file in general as it seems very fragile and rather an experimental feature to me. I switched to creating my own main and only read parts of config that are likely to change from own file. see it here: https://github.com/mohamnag/swarm-artemis-send-receive

Comment: for the sake of using hollow uberjar, I had to switch back to YAML config and surprisingly this config worked. I'm not sure if the problem was just that I had named all the socket and connector and connection factories the same or that the connectors and entries where here defined as arrays, but this worked!